# upgrade gwt 2.7 to gwt 2.8.1 not working

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I develop an application inwith gwt and the google app engine. untilUntil now i used withI have been using gwt 2.7 lib and google app engine 1.51 lib. i tryI want to upgrade thefrom gwt 2.7 to 2.8.1 lib and i have 2, but I am facing two problems now

i hope you can help me.

1) when i try to run the project i get exception in devModeBase.class

when i try to run the project i get exception in devModeBase.class
file in run method 
this is the log of run + exception:

```
 Running CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 65462, -
    sourceLevel, 1.8, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, -launcherDir, 
    /Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/war, -logLevel, INFO, -
    style, OBFUSCATED, com.darimpo.Darimpo, com.darimpo.Darimpo]
    Super Dev Mode starting up
    workDir: /var/folders/fj/8gtg078929j8hjtfzyy5srv40000gn/T/gwt-
    codeserver-8030568012575356208.tmp
    2017-05-10 06:44:10.582:INFO::main: Logging initialized @3822ms
    Loading Java files in com.darimpo.Darimpo.
    Ignored 33 units with compilation errors in first pass.
    Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see 
    all errors.
    Module setup completed in 4961 ms
    Loading Java files in com.darimpo.Darimpo.
    Ignored 33 units with compilation errors in first pass.
    Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see 
    all errors.
    Module setup completed in 1273 ms
    2017-05-10 06:44:15.046:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
    2017-05-10 06:44:15.164:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started 
    o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7a508fdc{/,null,AVAILABLE}
    2017-05-10 06:44:15.301:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started 
    ServerConnector@4ca4b342{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:65462}
    2017-05-10 06:44:15.313:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @8553ms

    The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:65462/
    Code server started in 6.828 s ms
    2017-05-10 06:44:15.702:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
    2017-05-10 06:44:19.948:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED 
  org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter@1e23623
    : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 

javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descr
    iptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJspConfig(TldScanner.java:148)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:760)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432)
2017-05-10 06:44:19.952:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload@eb55e46{/,file:/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/war/,STARTING}{/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/Darimpo/war}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJspConfig(TldScanner.java:148)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:760)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432)
2017-05-10 06:44:19.953:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler@113f4cb9: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJspConfig(TldScanner.java:148)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:760)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432)
2017-05-10 06:44:19.956:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@17c2393{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:49276}
2017-05-10 06:44:19.957:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6e1f3bb9: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJspConfig(TldScanner.java:148)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:760)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432)
```

2) when i try to compile the project i get this exception

```
   [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:111)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:76)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:331)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:94)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:139)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:135)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:786)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:778)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1401)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:896)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1410)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1222)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1140)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:255)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:255)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:202)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:143)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:204)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:155)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:144)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/HasMetaData
    at com.google.gwt.maps.jsio.rebind.JSWrapperGenerator.hasTag(JSWrapperGenerator.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.jsio.rebind.TaskFactory$FlyweightPolicy.shouldBind(TaskFactory.java:155)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.jsio.rebind.TaskFactory.extractMethods(TaskFactory.java:309)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.jsio.rebind.JSWrapperGenerator.generate(JSWrapperGenerator.java:314)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:745)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:262)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:251)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.PrecompilationContextCreator$1.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(PrecompilationContextCreator.java:86)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:519)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:487)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.maybeHandleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:415)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.visit(UnifyAst.java:402)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.HasMetaData
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 58 more
      [ERROR] at MapImpl.java(45): GWT.create(MapImpl.class)
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
      [ERROR] at MapImpl.java(45): (MapImpl) GWT.create(MapImpl.class)
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
      [ERROR] at MapImpl.java(45): final static MapImpl impl = (MapImpl) GWT.create(MapImpl.class)
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement
      [ERROR] at MapImpl.java(41): {
  final static MapImpl impl = (MapImpl) GWT.create(MapImpl.class);
}
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
      [ERROR] at MapImpl.java(41): {
  final static MapImpl impl = (MapImpl) GWT.create(MapImpl.class);
}
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
      [ERROR] at MapImpl.java(41): com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.MapImpl.$clinit()V
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
```

thank you every one

Answer (score 2):

I can comment on your point 2.

The class that it's complaining that it's missing (`com/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/HasMetaData`) does not exist in GWT 2.8.

So you're probably referencing old jars somewhere, such as gwt-dev/gwt-user 2.7, etc. This is likely to cause a whole host of other problems (not excluding the one described at 1.) ) so I'd fix this first, before looking someplace else.

Edit: Just noticed that you reference 2.8.1 and not 2.8.0; didn't knew that 2.8.1 was out. I just re-checked for 2.8.1 and my answer still applies.

Comment: Hello everyone
I managed to solve the problems in the attached link
Https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/-pkSYukW6gU/tssJsgE6AQAJ
But now I have new problems
1. I had to remove the following code from the web.xml file in order to solve the problem But i have this code because i want to use ssl